# problems with whitelisting https on phonegap

Tags: cordova, https, config

I am using ajax cors and everything works fine with http from phone and desktop. When I put https it doesn't.
Of course everything works fine with https from the browser so no problems with the service. 
I set up the config.xml as shown below but nothing the ajax always fails from the phone.

```
<access origin="https://*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="https://xxx.xxx.x.xx" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="https://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8000" subdomains="true" />

$.ajax 
({ 
type: "POST", 
url: 'https://mydomain.com:8000/login', 
crossDomain: true, 
async: false, 
beforeSend: function(xhr){ 
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + myKey) 
}, 
withCredentials: true 
}).done(function (res){ 
// do some stuff 
}).fail(function(error) { 
if(error.status == 401) 
alert("Te dhenat nuk jane te sakta"); 
else 
alert("Lidhja me serverin nuk u krye"); 
});
```

});

Comment: do you set access-origin * in config.xml

Comment: as you can see up there yes

Answer (score 0):

the server certificate must be a CA certificate not a self signed cert in order to work on android or iOS